# (Google) Title of page not updated, everything else did

Tags: google, search, seo, title, google-search-console

My website changed significantly this month.  Amongst the changes was the website's title.  Two weeks ago, I finally used Webmaster Tools and submitted the page.

So far, Yahoo and Bing have updated the title in the search results, but not Google.

I've resubmitted via Webmaster Tools the website, and the bots have crawled the page, and have added "content keywords".  But the title still doesn't match.  The "content keywords" lists many of the words in the new title (but contains keywords of the existing title also).  Must say that 4 of the top 5 key words in the "significance" list are the new title's.  Still, no change.

Any remedies for this problem?

Is adding the "alt" tag for the logo significant enough to trigger the change?

There isn't an appropriate place to put the company name between  tags on the front page.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Google may use old page titles for some time.  The only solution is to wait.  It also may depend on what you are searching for.  Google is known for rewriting page titles when they don't match the keywords being searched for.  One strategy that Google seems to use is to use an old page title if it better matches the keywords.  [Here is a forum thread about it at webmasterworld.com](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4511627.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am searching with the words in the new title, but the search result shows the previous title.

Answer (score 1):

Per Google, they will do rewrites of your "Title" tags sometimes as noted above.

http://insidesearch.blogspot.ca/2012/06/search-quality-highlights-39-changes.html
Here are the details from the update:

"Trigger alt title when HTML title is truncated. [launch codename "tomwaits", project codename "Snippets"] We have algorithms designed to present the best possible result titles. This change will show a more succinct title for results where the current title is so long that it gets truncated. We'll only do this when the new, shorter title is just as accurate as the old one."

So, you may not get a Title tag showing in the SERPs as you exactly want.